# How do I make component instances inherit links from a master component in Adobe XD?

Tags: components, adobe, instance, adobe-xd

A - master component, B,C,D - its instances. Master component has a button that leads to F frame. How do I make buttons in B,C,D leads to F too?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that if you create "A" as the master component (with the links set) and then switch to the "Prototype" screen, you can copy the master component creating a new version: "B", which will also include the same links. Then you can override with anything specific to "B".

Hope this helps.